# AngularJS : ng-repeat not executing inside scoped directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

Run into an issue where ng-repeat doesn't seem to be executing inside a custom directive. I think the problem is something to do with the transclusion/scope but I'm not really sure.

directive:

```
.directive('node', ['$compile', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            obj: '=obj',
        },
        transclude: true,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transclude) {
            transclude(scope, function(clone, scope) {
                console.log(clone);
                var tmp = angular.element('<div></div>'), template;
                tmp.append(clone);
                if(scope.obj.hasSub) {
                    template =
                        '<div>' +
                          '<span>{{obj.name}}</span>' +
                          '<ul>' +
                              '<li ng-repeat="child in obj.children">' +
                                '<node data-obj="child" >' + tmp.html() + '</browser-node>' +
                              '</li>' +
                          '</ul>' +
                        '</div>';
                } else {
                  template = 
                    '<div>' +
                      tmp.html() +
                    '</div>'
                }
                element.html('').append($compile(template)(scope));
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

controller:

```
.controller('Main', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [
    {'name': 'one', hasSub: true, children: [
      { 'name': 'one-one', items: { foo: 3, bar: 2 } } 
    ] },
    {'name': 'two', hasSub: true, children: [
      { 'name': 'two-one', items: { foo: 6, bar: 5 } } 
    ] }
  ];
}]);
```

html:

```
   <ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in items">
    <node obj="item">
      {{obj.name}}
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="(k,v) in obj.items">{{k}}: {{v}}</li>
      </ul>
    </node>
</ul>
```

The name of the item node displays fine, and `{{obj.items}}` will output the correct contents, but the ng-repeat seems to do nothing.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3nYbSzxTWaWsfBDwrD4u?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

There is no property `items` in the first level of your data. If you nest the repeater for `items` in your template and change to `child.items` it works fine

```
template =
    '<div>' +
      '<span>{{obj.name}}</span>' +
      '<ul>' +
          '<li ng-repeat="child in obj.children">' +
            '<node data-obj="child" >' + tmp.html() + '</node>' +
            '<ul>'+
            '<li ng-repeat="(k,v) in child.items">{{k}}: {{v}}</li>'+
          '</ul>'+
          '</li>' +
      '</ul>' +
    '</div>';
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZJZN0ixsd4vNSHjvfb8w?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: The first level doesn't have `items` and the repeat that's failing isn't meant to be executed for that level (`hasSub` is set to true for the objects in the first level, not in the children). I don't have the repeater in the template because I want to be able to reuse the directive elsewhere and display the final children elements differently. (i.e. iterate over an `items` property here, only display the `name` property in a different use, etc)

Comment: if you want this to be portable, use a uniform data structure with same properties at each level. I only pointed out where your properties didn't match . You can easily go many levels deep using `ng-if` in template and not switching between repeaters on objects and repeaters on array.

Comment: This just happens to have `items` that I want to iterate over and display in an entirely different way than `children` on the parent. It's intended to be used with a structure along the lines of `[{name: 'foo', children: [{name: 'bar', children: [{name: 'this is the last child to be iterated over in this way', items: {foo: 3, bar: 5}}, ...]}, ... ]` and then reused elsewhere were the final child won't have an items property and it'll just display the item name and say a button with a click handler or something

Comment: this [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/4HUrRSToXeU9mcmfAThF?p=preview) illustrates what I want to achieve better I think

Comment: it's a lot easier to push  an item into an array to add though...or to remove